# Grammatical mistake in sentences

Tags: grammar

I have no idea what's wrong with those sentence. thanks for helping me. :)

1:Smith et.al(2000) reports that this level of violence is harmful

2:(Patel,cited from Bragg,2003)

3:The failure of cells from removing sugars causes diabetes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Smith et al means "Smith and the others", and is therefore plural, so the sentence should read "Smith et al report that...". The sentence is also missing a period.

2) If there is problem there, I'm not sure what it is.

3) The more conventional usage would "The failure of cells *to* remove..." or "the failure of cells *in* removing...">

Comment: 2:(Patel,cited from Bragg,2003)is a in-text reference,and it doesn't followed the in-text reference rule :)